# metro.config.js Using NativeWind and SVG transformer

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, svg

I've been searching for hours how to mix NativeWind and SVG reader for react native application, here's the answer for me:

Answer (score 0):

**Expo**:

> "expo": "^50.0.1",

**ReactNative**:

> "react-native": "0.73.2",

Hope it helps.

---

metro.config.js (root of the project)

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");
const { withNativeWind } = require("nativewind/metro");

const createConfig = () => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

  const { transformer, resolver } = config;

  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
  };
  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"]
  };
  return config;
};

const config = createConfig();
module.exports = withNativeWind(config, { input: "./src/global.css" , });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my article for react native tailwind and setup it in just `2 minutes`

Medium Link: [Tailwind CSS In React Native](https://medium.com/@aqeel_ahmad/tailwind-css-in-react-native-2024-ac4cc7973446)

hope it will help you.